# kotlin- Bundle pass null to other fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

I have simple app that has 1 activity and two fragments one of them display RecyclerView with OnClickListener to replace the fragment
now I need to send data from that arraylist RecyclerView  with the click to other fragment and I don't know where I must type the Bundle and how

Answer (score 0):

Your main culprit is  ft1.replace(R.id.MainFram,SubMark()) instead you must use   ft1.replace(R.id.MainFram,subMark) subMark variable. You are calling new instance of Fragment instead of fragment with bundle. Use these piece of code

```
  val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("data", "nasser") 
    val subMark = SubMark()
    subMark.arguments = bundle
    var ft1 : FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction() 
    ft1.replace(R.id.MainFram,subMark) ft1.commit()
```

And access data with

```
 String name = getArguments().getString("key");
```

Comment: I have some think like this already but ny problem is Bundle always send null what i can do

Comment: Check your data before attachment

Comment: Like .toString () ?

Comment: in MainActivity_____
    override fun onItemClicked(Data:MainMarkModling) {

          val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("data", "nasser")

            val subMark = SubMark()
            subMark.arguments = bundle

        var ft1 : FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft1.replace(R.id.MainFram,SubMark())
        ft1.commit()
    }_____*_____
in fragment
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var args = arguments?.getString("data")
        tit = args.toString()
    }

Comment: you must use ft1.replace(R.id.MainFram,subMark)  instead   of ft1.replace(R.id.MainFram,SubMark())

Comment: Thank you i try other thing and i fix it